# Optaplanner VRP and vehicle have break while on route

Tags: drools-planner, optaplanner

Dear all Optaplanners

Would you know if it's possible to assign kind of break time for a vehicle being on route. In Switzerland it is the law to have 15 Minutes break but I am not sure how to implement this?

Thank you and Best Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you're adjusting the timewindowed VRP example, and you need to take a 15 minute break every 2 hours, just the class `ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener` to add an extra 15 minutes if the ride takes longer than 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. How would you implement to have more on control on the period of the break or "time out". Let's say my driver is planned to take a break between 09:45 and 10:15 for example. Best Regards Paul